# Change windows user name display format

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-account

My Microsoft account's full name is displayed with firstName-lastName format in my profile page in Microsoft website, but with lastName-firstName format on my windows computer (on lock screen), is it possible to change which format to adopt on Windows ?

I've tried running `NETPLWIZ` and then writing my full name how i want it to be displayed instead, but after login-out and in again it returns to the previous state, so i guess this method only works for local accounts.

**EDIT :**
This is not a duplicate question, my problem is not with displaying the full name, but rather how it is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to change it. Go to Computer Management (right click on My PC and select Properties). Then Local Users and Groups. Users and right click on "you".  Change the Full Name. That is not your account so it should change fine

Comment: unfortunately not working, produces the same results as the method I tried, it shows it correctly when i sign out, but as soon as I enter my password it returns to its previous state, because it's linked to my Microsoft account.

Comment: Interesting. Works here with a Microsoft Account.  Make a new test Windows User Account, log into the new Windows Account and see if you can change the name in the new account.

Comment: Made another test account, signed in, it didn't show the full name at first, i had to change it from the admin's account and it worked, I can sign in and out without it being altered on the test accout now.

Comment: So you are good to go now?